# UINavigationBar height too tall on iPhone5 simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have embedded a viewcontroller into a NavigationController in Xcode Version 9.2.

The navbar looks good in the iPhone 7 emulator, but when it is in the iPhone 5 simulator, it is disproportionately tall. I have already tried setting the Prompt text to nil.

[iPhone 7 simulator (good)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5iqz.png)

[iPhone 5 simulator(bad)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0a4PF.png)

On the root view controller of the `UINavigationController`:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated { 
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated]; 
    self.navigationItem.prompt = nil; 
    [super viewWillAppear:animated]; 
} 

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated { 
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated]; 
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated]; 
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code for the navigation controller or view controller that you can show? It's hard to determine the problem without more information.

Comment: Are you using auto layout or autoresizing mask?

Comment: @Alexander i am using auto layout

Comment: Are you using Interface builder or code for UI?

Comment: @Jake on the root view controller of the uinavigation controller: ` - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
      self.navigationItem.prompt = nil;
    
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
} `

Comment: @Jake I also set the navbar title font, color, and bar tint color in the AppDelegate

Comment: @Alexander mostly interface builder, except the revisions i mentioned above